# How do you open a wwwrooot folder from Visual Studio without the .project or the solution file on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio

So I downloaded a wwwroot from an ftp file and the website was made from visual studio. The file consists a wwwroot which I know can be opened from a windows computer through open website and then you can just link to that folder. However I need to do it on a mac. Is there anyway to open the folder so I can edit the file on my mac? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use any text editor/your preferred IDE?   Check out VSCode:   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Comment: I need to take over the project and the current trace I only have of the project is from the ftp.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'current trace'?  What's stopping you editing the source files with any text editor?  What is it you're asking - please can you expand the question?

Comment: Hey 83N. Basically I want to get the Solution file from the wwwroot. I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to know if there is a way.